# Function return tuple and the result is assigned to new variables

Tags: f#

I've just started learning F# very recently. I have a function which counts the coefficients of the linear equation: `y = ax + b`, based on coordinates of two points `P1(x1, y1)`, `P2(x1, y2)`. The function looks like this:

```
module LinearFit

let generate(x1 : double, y1 : double, x2 : double, y2 : double) = 
    let w = x1 * 1.0 - x2 * 1.0
    let wa = y1 * 1.0 - y2 * 1.0
    let wb = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1     


    printfn "w: %g" w
    printfn "wa: %g" wa
    printfn "wb: %g" wb

    let a = wa/w
    let b = wb/w

    printfn "a: %g" a
    printfn "b: %g" b


    printfn "%g %g" a b
    (a, b)
```

I'm trying to somehow return founded coefficients as a tuple result and then assign the result to the new variables so later I can use the result to do some other operations. The trivial thing, for now, would be just displayed a result like:

```
The generated function is y = 2.5x - 6.5
```

So far I was trying to do sth like this

```
open System

let main() =
    printf "Linear fit"
    (a: double, b: double) <- LinearFit.generate(5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 11.0) 
    printfn "The generated functi..."

main()

Console.ReadKey()  |> ignore
```

This is only a concept as I'm not even able to compile the project as im getting errors:

```
"Unexpected symbol ',' in expression"

"Unexpected symbol ')' in binding."
```

I tried to find some similar approach to C#...
For now what I want to achieve is just to assing the result of `generate` function to some variables. In C# it would look just like

```
public (double a, double b) Generate(some params here)
{
    // some logic here
    return (a, b);
}
(var a, var b) = Generate(...);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem? What about your attempt does not work?

Comment: nope, it doesn't work :/

Comment: "Doesn;t work" is not a useful problem description. What tells you that it doesn't work?

Comment: Ok, good, please edit the question to include the complete error message, and indicate where it occurs. Also, you might want to have a look at [ask].

Comment: let a, b = generate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making several syntactic mistakes.

First, the arrow-left operator `<-` is *destructive update*. It takes a *mutable variable* on the right and an expression on the left, and pushes the value of the expression into the variable. For example:

```
let mutable x = 5
x <- 42
```

In your example, neither `a` nor `b` are mutable variables that exist by the time you're trying to use the `<-` operator. Plus, the operator expects a *single mutable variable*, not a pattern.

Second, the way to declare new variables in F# is with `let`. It is roughly equivalent to `var` in C#, except you can declare multiple variables at once by putting them in a pattern. For example:

```
let x = 42
let pair = (1, 5)
let a, b = pair
```

Here, on the last line, I'm declaring two variables `a` and `b` by destructuring the `pair`.

In your example, you're trying to introduce the two new variables `a` and `b` without a `let` keyword. This is not allowed.

---

So, putting all of the above together, this is the right way to do what you're trying to do:

```
let main() =
    printf "Linear fit"
    let a, b = LinearFit.generate(5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 11.0) 
    printfn "The generated functi..."
```

---

P.S. Your question betrays a misunderstanding of some pretty basic principles of F# syntax. Because of this, I would recommend that you read through tutorials, examples, and other articles on F# to familiarize yourself with the syntax before attempting to venture farther.

Comment: and how would you display the result? not sure how to do string interpolation in F#...

Comment: I stand by my recommendation to read up on F# before venturing further. For example, [the very first Google result for "F# printfn"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS837US839&ei=spBlXZ_5EIKD5wK55bSwBQ&q=f%23+printfn&oq=f%23+printfn&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i20i263j0j0i22i30l7.14369.15545..15875...0.3..0.82.601.8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i67.Je056ccXqyo&ved=0ahUKEwifmpGZ8KPkAhWCwVkKHbkyDVYQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) explains how it works.

Comment: `printf "The generated function looks like y = %gx + %g" a b` works. Thanks